# How to get property of a object when dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck in a problem I have a array like:

```
[
  [{"Id":"10009"},{"Name":"TEST 2"}],
  [{"Phone":"77777777"},{"Fax":"null"}],
  [{"Description":"null"},{"Type":"null"}],
  [{"Website":"null"}]
]
```

It holds the sub array of objects and each object has its own property, the problem is we can use the objects as **obj.Id or obj.Name** etc but how to use in this case as I don't want to hard code the **.propert**, also I can use **obj[]** approch but here I am not getting the property name.

What to do?

Comment: `yourArray[0][0].id` returns the `id` property's value.

Comment: yes yourArray[0].id will return the id property but I don't want to hard code this as there are different properties.. kind of a dynamic code

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is not very friendly for accessing specific property values.  If that were my data and I had control over the structure, I'd redesign it to be more suitable for the type of access you need.  A primary goal in data structure design is that the structure is set up for the way you want to look things up in it.  Your data structure is not good at all for looking up a specific property (to tell you the truth, I'm not sure what it is optimized for).

As you have it now, the only way to find a specific property without hardcoding a given index value in the arrays is to search for it manually.

So, if you were looking for the `Id` property, you could do this:

```
var info = [
  [{"Id":"10009"},{"Name":"TEST 2"}],
  [{"Phone":"77777777"},{"Fax":"null"}],
  [{"Description":"null"},{"Type":"null"}],
  [{"Website":"null"}]
]

function findPropValue(data, propName) {
    data.forEach(function(current) {
        current.forEach(function(item) {
            if (propName in item) {
                return item[propName];
            }
        });
    });
}

var id = findPropValue(info, "Id");
```

---

FYI, your data would be a whole lot easier to deal with like this:

```
var info = [
  {"Id":"10009", "Name":"TEST" ,"Phone":"77777777","Fax":"null","Description":"null","Type":"null","Website":"null"},
  {"Id":"10010", "Name":"TEST2" ,"Phone":"88888888","Fax":"null","Description":"null","Type":"null","Website":"null"}
];
```

Comment: @user614946 - code added (patience, it takes time to write some code).

Comment: @user614946 - why do you have such an impractical and hard-to-use data structure?

Comment: I wanted to implement pagination over a single objects fields.. like 2 fields user enters data and then click on next also I dont want to make different modules and use hard coding

Comment: @user614946 - pagination over object fields?  Huh?  There's no "javascript" reason to do that.  Why aren't all these properties on a single object?  Why a 2D array?  It's just a painful data structure to deal with and I see no obvious use for the complication.  For N items, you would have a single array of objects where each object has all the properties that go together for one item.  That's way, way easier to deal with that this.

Comment: Yes you are correct but then I am not able to do pagiantion.. If you have some other method then please let me know.. the pagination is only on the fields of a single object

Comment: What is "pagination in a data structure"?  Pagination sounds like a display characteristic.  You should handle that in the display code, not in the storage code.

Comment: yes but this is a new concept I am developing to handle single objects  property in pagination.. lets see

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over properties

```
angular.foreach(outerarray, function(array){
    var obj = {};
    angular.foreach(array, function(property){
          for(prop in property) {
                obj[prop] = property[prop]
          }

      });
});
```

what this will do is convert your array into

```
{"Id":"10009","Name":"TEST2","Phone":"77777777","Fax":"null","Description":"null","Type":"null","Website":"null"}
```

Comment: that is the problem I don't want to pars this in a single Array..